# How does Firebase javascript .on('value') callbacks work?

Tags: javascript, sockets, firebase, webhooks

I am wondering how one could go about implementing something similar to what firebase does with:

```
firebaseRef.on('child_removed', function(oldChildSnapshot) {
  // code to handle child removal.
});
```

How could you write a server that does this? Are they using webhooks behind the scene? How is it calling the function when the value changes?

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use websockets to achieve this functionality. Checkout [FeathersJS](http://feathersjs.com/). You can use a socketio listener or an adapter such as can.feathers(canjs). An adapter could exist for other frameworks such as Angular, but doesn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are pretty good examples for open client/server websockets.

You should use the power of [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) and [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), it look like the best way to do it, of you dont want to use tools like Firebase or GoInstant!